# Что означает "->" в выводе команды ls -l?

Tags: linux, symlinks, ls

Что для команды

```
ls -l /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/host.conf
```

означает вывод

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/host.conf -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/host.conf
```

?

Comment: Оставляю на собственный вопрос  здесь ответ, потому как потратил чрезвычайно много времени на его поиск.
Надеюсь, кому-либо еще он будет полезен.
Если есть где-либо некорректная формулировка - дайте знать. Внесу дополнения.

Comment: Почитайте побольше об именах в \*nix-ах (hard и symbolic links). Например, (первая попавшаяся в гугле  ссылка) [тут](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108771/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hard-link-and-a-symbolic-link)

Comment: @avp
Хм. Про "жесткие" ссылки не имел понятия.
В таком случае является ли "жесткая" ссылка фактически отдельным файлом с данными (абсолютной копией) того файла, на который она указывает, позволяя при этом обновлять свое содержимое в соответствии с обновлениями файла, на который она указывает?

Comment: Суть в том, что "истинное имя" файла (т.е. массива байт на носителе), это номер в таблице объектов файловой системы  (inode, его можно увидеть в выводе `ls -i`), а то имя, что мы обычно видим, это символьная строка в каталоге (директории), связанная с этим номером.  Таких имен (именно они называются hard link) можно сделать много, даже в разных каталогах (но в одной и той же файловой системе). А symbolic link это строка, которая вместо номера связана с другой строкой (которая рассматривается как имя файла (или каталога)). Symlinks могут ссылаться на объекты в другой файловой системе.

Comment: Если кратко, то hard links это не копии, а разные пути доступа к одному и тому же файлу (данным на диске). Все они равноправны.

Answer (score 6):

Вывод `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/host.conf -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/host.conf`

на команду

```
ls -l /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/host.conf
```

означает, что `sites-enabled/host.conf` - симлинк (symlink) на `sites-available/host.conf`

И соответственно все изменения, отражаемые в `sites-available/host.conf` будут актуальны для сервисов, работающих с `sites-enabled/host.conf`

Comment: `ярылк по сути` - в корне неверно. «ярлык» в терминологии ms/windows - совершенно иная сущность, нежели unix-овая символическая ссылка. в частности потому, что, например, в файловой системе ms/ntfs прекрасно себе существует [одноимённая сущность](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_NTFS) (правда, не знаю, насколько её реализация и поведение совпадают с unix-овыми).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin
Хм. Тогда какая аналогия будет наиболее корректной? И верно ли я сформулировал хотя бы суть функциональности симлинка? Если верно, тогда уточнение в скобках про ярлык просто удалю.

Comment: а ms/windows-овской сущности «ярлык», вероятно, **примерно** соответствуют т.н. [desktop-файлы](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html). правда, опять-таки, затрудняюсь сказать, до какой степени простирается это соответствие).

Comment: `Тогда какая аналогия будет наиболее корректной?` - да никакая. если речь об утомлённых замечательной операционной системой ms/windows - я же привёл выше ссылку, что и в ms/windows (хотя бы в некоторых её родных файловых системах) также существуют символические ссылки.

Comment: Суть в том, что открыавая файл с именем `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/host.conf` вы на самом деле открываете файл `/etc/nginx/sites-available/host.conf`

Comment: @avp да, этот момент я понял, его я в последних абзацах и отразил. Потому первая аналогия, что у меня в голове возникла - с ярлыками рабочего стола на Windows - когда запуская посредством ярлыка программу мы фактически открываем файл, находящийся обычно в Program Files. И тогда ярлык на рабочем столе не является ни отдельной программой, ни отдельным скриптом или чем-либо прочим.